# Wrong parsing with iText's PdfTextExtractor

Tags: java, itext

I'm facing a problem when I try to read the content of a PDF document. I'm using **iText 2.1.7** with Java, and I need to analyze the content of a PDF document: at first I was using the **PdfTextExtractor**'s **getTextFromPage** method and it was working right, but only when the page is just text, if it contains an image, then the String that I get with the getTextFromPage is a set of meaningless symbols (maybe a different character encoding?), and I lose the content of the whole page. I tried with the last version of iText and works fine, but if I'm not wrong the license wouldn't be totally free (I'm working in a web application for a commercial customer, which serves PDFs on the fly) so I can't use it. I would really appreciate if you have any suggestion.

In case you need it, here is the code:

```
PdfReader pdf = new PdfReader(doc);  //doc is just a byte[]
int pageCount = pdf.getNumberOfPages();
for (int i = 1; i <= pageCount; i++) {
    PdfTextExtractor pdfTextExtractor = new PdfTextExtractor(pdf);
    String pageText = pdfTextExtractor.getTextFromPage(i);
```

Thanks in advance, regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you PDF has an inline image. I do not think that iText 2.1.7 will deal with that. 
You can find information regarding the license [here](http://itextpdf.com/terms-of-use/index.php)

Comment: Hi Eriksberger, thanks for your response, I think that probably you're right, I was reading the changelog for iText 5.0.4 [here](http://itextpdf.com/history/?branch=50&node=504) and there had been lot of work in PDF inline images. I will wait to see if someone knows an alternative for previous versions of iText. Thanks again.

Comment: I'm not aware of any forks, if that's what you mean.  You could release your app under the AGPL too.  Or you could pony up the dough.  If all you need is generic text extraction, there are other Java libraries floating around that can handle it.

Comment: Hi Mark, thanks for your response, after comment this issue with the rest of the team we decide to try out the [PdfBox](http://pdfbox.apache.org/). Thanks a lot to you and @Eriksberger for your time.